# api.get(...).then(...).catch(...).finally is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a React Native API call I am making.

Theoretically it should work -

```
    import API from "../../utils/API";

  componentDidMount() {
    let merchantId = this.props.merchant.id;
    let api = new API(this.props.gatheredTokens);
    let self = this;
    api.setRetry(10);
    api
      .get("merchantMessages", { repl_str: merchantId })
      .then(response => this.merchantMessageConfiguration(response.data))
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(function () {
        self.state.list.push(
          <Card
            merchant={self.props.merchant}
            key={self.props.merchant.id}
            bubblemsg={self.state.bubblemsg}
          />
        );
      })
      .finally(function () {
        self.merchantNoticeLoading(self);
      });
  }
```

However I am getting the following error:

[image: TypeError]

What is causing this error? The code looks valid.

Here is what get is:

```
 get(API, params = this.defaultParams) {
    this.call = "GET";
    let constructedURL = this.constructURL(API, params);
    axiosRetry(axios, { retries: this.retry });
    return axios.get(constructedURL, this.config);
  }
```

Comment: Does `.get` return a Promise-like object that implements the `.finally` method? It sounds like it doesn't (in environments that support `.finally`, it's only guaranteed to exist on *native Promises* constructed with `new Promise`, I believe - which is a pretty unfortunate source of confusion)

Comment: Get is just a wrapper for an axios call. I'll add it.

Comment: The explicit Promise construction antipattern could solve it, but I bet there's a better way

Comment: @nivendha .get is a method of API

Comment: @CertainPerformance - oh there's specific environmental rules when it comes to finally?

Comment: The only place `.finally` is in the specification is [Promise.prototype.finally()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally). But there are many thenables (often exposed by libraries) which do *not* inherit from `Promise.prototype`, which means that although you can call `.then` and `.catch` on them as if it was a native Promise, it's not a native Promise, so you can't use `.finally` with them.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I suggest to use another `then` instead of using `finally`. `then` after `catch` is works like a `finally`. don't forget to use at least one `catch` in your promise chain, in order to handle your instructions failure.

So this two line of code is the same:

```
api.get(…).then(…).catch(…).then(...)
```

and

```
api.get(…).then(…).catch(…).finally(...)
```

Comment: This works. But why can't I use finally() if I'm developing a modern application for modern browsers and this method is documented in MDN?

Comment: @Sadegh Teimori  the `.then()` block(which is being used as finally) after `.catch()` doesn't get called when the execution goes into `.catch()`. Any solution?

Comment: @Sadegh Why are you suggesting this? Is something wrong with `.finally()` in modern browsers?

Comment: `.finally()` doesn't supported by all of browsers. To ensure my code works on the all browser, i always use `.catch()` followed by `.then()`, instead of `.finally()`.

Comment: In my case Jimp resets Promise.prototype to ES5 level, so `finally` presents at app start and it is gone after jimp import

Answer (score 8):

Only a native Promise (constructed with `new Promise`) is guaranteed to have a `.finally` method (in newer environments). (in older environments, `.finally` won't work at all with Promises created with `new Promise`)

It looks like axios *doesn't* use `new Promise` internally - rather, it just returns a thenable, which is not guaranteed to have a `finally` method (and because it doesn't, it throws an error).

While you could use the explicit Promise construction antipattern to wrap the axios call in a *native* `new Promise`, so that it has `Promise.prototype.finally` in its prototype chain, a better option ([thanks Bergi!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57883187/api-get-then-catch-finally-is-not-a-function/57883380?noredirect=1#comment116203911_57883380)) is to just use `Promise.resolve`, which will turn a thenable into a native Promise while preserving the failure or success of the thenable:

```
get(API, params = this.defaultParams) {
  this.call = "GET";
  let constructedURL = this.constructURL(API, params);
  axiosRetry(axios, { retries: this.retry });
  return Promise.resolve(axios.get(constructedURL, this.config));
}
```

Comment: You still should avoid the [`new Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it). To coerce a thenable to a native promise, write `return Promise.resolve(axios.get(…));`, nothing more.

Comment: Oh, so `Promise.resolve` will allow rejections to pass through without causing issues, very cool! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The promise should be taking `finally` of es6, which I am not sure is something that gets supported by the `axios` promise, if I may, I sugest use `then` instead of `finally`

```
import API from "../../utils/API";

componentDidMount() {
let merchantId = this.props.merchant.id;
let api = new API(this.props.gatheredTokens);
let self = this;
api.setRetry(10);
api
  .get("merchantMessages", { repl_str: merchantId })
  .then(response => this.merchantMessageConfiguration(response.data))
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    self.state.list.push(
      <Card
        merchant={self.props.merchant}
        key={self.props.merchant.id}
        bubblemsg={self.state.bubblemsg}
      />
    );
  })
  .then(function () {
    self.merchantNoticeLoading(self);
  });
 }
```

Comment: use `require('promise.prototype.finally')` if u need the finally support ,
`finally` function will added to the `Promise.prototype`

Comment: the `.then()` after `.catch()` doesn't get called when the execution goes into `.catch()`. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could add this somewhere in the beginning of your code:

```
if (Promise.prototype.finally == null) {
    Promise.prototype.finally = function (handler) {
        return this.then(handler, handler);
    }
}
```

Fiddle to test it: https://jsfiddle.net/m63kgq7f/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a npm package [promise.prototype.finally](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise.prototype.finally) for polyfill.

doing like this:

```js
var promiseFinally = require('promise.prototype.finally');
promiseFinally.shim();
```

or in TypeScript:

```
//@ts-expect-error
import promiseFinally from 'promise.prototype.finally';

promiseFinally.shim();
```

The package will override the function if `Promise.prototype.finally` is not found in user browser. And if the browser support `Promise.prototype.finally`, it will just use the native function.

I use `Create React App` for building frontend project. It seems that Babel and TypeScript won't manage with this tough things, you should deal with it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the api in your get function like this:

```
 import API from "../../utils/API";

  componentDidMount() {
    let merchantId = this.props.merchant.id;
    let api = new API(this.props.gatheredTokens);
    let self = this;
    api.setRetry(10);

     get(api + "/merchantMessages", { repl_str: merchantId })
      .then(response => this.merchantMessageConfiguration(response.data))
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(function () {
        self.state.list.push(
          <Card
            merchant={self.props.merchant}
            key={self.props.merchant.id}
            bubblemsg={self.state.bubblemsg}
          />
        );
      })
      .finally(function () {
        self.merchantNoticeLoading(self);
      });
  }
```

Comment: I've answered according to the get function you presented in the end of your question.

Comment: You have to import your get function and use it in your component.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem once but it was exclusive with Firefox, but I still needed to do some code after resolving or rejection, so I used `async/await` form.

```js
import API from "../../utils/API";

componentDidMount() {
let merchantId = this.props.merchant.id;
let api = new API(this.props.gatheredTokens);
let self = this;
api.setRetry(10);
(async () => {
    try {
        const response = await api.get("merchantMessages", { repl_str: merchantId })
        this.merchantMessageConfiguration(response.data)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } finally {
        self.state.list.push(
            <Card
                merchant={self.props.merchant}
                key={self.props.merchant.id}
                bubblemsg={self.state.bubblemsg}
            />
       );
    }  
})()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = 'https://api.github.com/users/hadley/orgs';
fetchJson(url)
.then((obj) =>{ 
    console.log('obj') 
    console.log(obj) 
    console.log('obj') 
})
.catch((error) =>{ 
    console.log('error') 
    console.log(error) 
    console.log('error') 
})
.finally(() => { 
    console.log('WHALE HELLO THERE ') 
});
```

Answer (score -6):

try to avoid using .finally(). That's it.

Comment: You should at least axplain your answer.